# Was there ever a war mission where the personnel were instructed to surrender when the mission complete?

Tags: military, war, warfare

For instance, an air raid beyond bomber's range where after completing the mission the pilots should land or eject at the enemy land and surrender.

Comment: There were several examples where the missions were intended to end in neutral territory, with the crews involved surrendering to the neutral authorities, would those count?

Comment: And of course there were missions were the personnel was instructed to die, which is usually worse than surrender.

Comment: @SJuan76 I mean motivating the personnel to die may be more difficult (depending on culture) than surrender.

Comment: It seems to be more usual to have a planned way out, as a hope, even if the personel are aware that it may well not work. The [St Nazaire Raid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St_Nazaire_Raid) is an example: only 228 of 611 attackers escaped, with 215 being made prisoner, and 169 dying. It was nonetheless considered a success.

Comment: @JohnDallman My first thought was St Nazaire too ... but you're right, it would be unusual to have absolutely no plan to attempt to escape. I also thought about the Dolittle raids, where the "escape plan" involved landing in occupied China, and hoping friendly forces would be the first to find them. I don't think that counts either, as they certainly wouldn't want to be captured by the Japanese.

Comment: I doubt you'll find anything in the modern era; every soldier's obligation is to resist capture and attempt escape. But if you go back to the medieval era, when ransom was the norm, you might find something.

Comment: During [Prague offensive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prague_Offensive) Nazi army received an order to fight against the Soviet army and to retreat until they are able to surrender to "the allies". Is it OK?

Comment: Against...small scale counter intel. "Assassinate, get arrested, get freed." the Battle is a psychological one (French Resistance for example) and can really wear an occupying force down. Happens all the time in the War on Terror. Think Dakota Access Pipeline attacks for example.

Comment: Doolittle raid?

Comment: "Plan A" for Doolittle raid was landing on China (allied, and the chinese were expecting them). Landing in the Soviet Union was a "plan B", if reaching china was unfeasible, as it happened for some of the planes.

Comment: Are we counting the last days of the European theater in WWII, when (according to legend) German units would deliberately surrender to American or British forces in order to avoid having to surrender to Soviet forces?

Answer (score 2):

During B-29 raids on Japan in 1944, in July and November, three B-29 bombers were forced to land in the Soviet Union either because of battle damage or fuel exhaustion after raids on Japanese positions in Manchuria.
Because the Soviets were still not formally at war with Japan at this point, they interned the bombers' crews and happily accepted the windfall of the B-29s, a bomber they had unsuccessfully tried to get from the US.

Although these B-29 crews were not technically prisoners of an enemy, they were effectively out of the war.  At this point in the Pacific Theater, becoming a prisoner of the Japanese was more than likely a death sentence, so internment in the Soviet Union was the only viable option to crews whose bombers could not return to their island bases.

Comment: But were they instructed to surrender?

Comment: The Sovjets weren't considered enemies at the time.

Comment: In this case, I would say, "turn themselves in," rather than "surrender."

Comment: Because the Soviet Union was not

Comment: An even more older equivalent example would be the Doolittle raid in 1942

Comment: Stalin demanded that his designers replicate the B-29.  While they never were able to produce the flush cockpit glazing, They did include a crude patch over skin damage to one of the real B-29s in all of their replicas.